# JXLS - how to create hyperlink to Excel worksheets in workbook

Tags: java, jxls

I am trying to create an Excel workbook with with [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/). I want a text hyperlink for navigating through worksheets in a workbook. I couldn't find any helpful information online. Please give any idea or hyperlink for that can help to to solve the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[jXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) is a small and easy-to-use Java library for writing Excel files using XLS templates and reading data from Excel into Java objects using XML configuration. If you are trying to create hyerlink, jXLS doen't have low lever excel manupulation capability. But you can to use [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) a free library. This code create hyperlink to a Cell for that task  as shown below.

```
        //creating the cell
        Row row = my_sheet.createRow(0);                
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);

        //creating helper class
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        XSSFCreationHelper helper= workbook.getCreationHelper();

        //creating the hyperlink
        link = helper.createHyperlink(HSSFHyperlink.LINK_DOCUMENT);
        link.setAddress("'target_worksheet_name'!A1");

        //optional hyperlink style
        XSSFCellStyle hlinkstyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
        XSSFFont hlinkfont = workbook.createFont();
        hlinkfont.setUnderline(XSSFFont.U_SINGLE);
        hlinkfont.setColor(HSSFColor.BLUE.index);
        hlinkstyle.setFont(hlinkfont);

        //applying the hyperlink to the cell
        cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

Answer (score 3):

jxls supports Parameterized formulas, you can probably

use cell with a formula like below
=HYPERLINK("http://test.com/", "Click ME")

Parameterize it in cell with 
=HYPERLINK(${paramLink}, ${paramDisplay})

pass parameters to jxls context and they will be rendered as proper link

http://jxls.sourceforge.net/samples/param_formulas.html

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but another possible solution is to use JXLS 2+ and the `PoiTransformer`. It has a utility class called `PoiUtil` which can be injected to the context.

```
final var transformer = PoiTransformer.createTransformer(inputStream, outputStream);

// it is important to create the context like this
// or you can manually insert the PoiUtil instance if you wish

final var context = PoiTransformer.createInitialContext();
// setup your context...

JxlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(context, transformer);
```

And in the template you can use it like this: `${util.hyperlink(linkVar, titleVar)}` where the `linkVar` and `titleVar` are the corresponding variables in the context.